# Understanding hachnasas orchim

Tags: mitzvah, home-house, hachnasat-orchim-guests

Is hachnasas orchim (welcoming guests) a mitzvah (either of biblical or rabbinic origin)? If not why is it considered more important than greeting the divine presence (bereshis 18:3 Rashi)? Does it have technical mitzvah parameters - for example is it still 'welcoming guests' if it is a relative? if you don't own the home itself? for a minor? etc.

Comment: *Hachnasas or'chim* is a *kiyum* of *g'milus chasadim* ([Shabbos 127b](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=377&size=2)).

Comment: @Fred there must be some difference; or do we say g'milus chasadim is more important than the revelation of God's presence?

Comment: @nikmasi The former is a subcategory of the latter, by which I mean it is one way of fulfilling *g'milus chasadim*. Perhaps there are differences between the subcategories, but the overarching mitzvah is *g'milus chasadim*.

Comment: Special case: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43627

Answer (score 2):

The *Sefer HaChaim* [3:3 (by Rabbi Chaim ben Betzalel - brother of the *Maharal*)] says, *"Inviting your relatives (to your house) is in essence, is the main mitzvah of HaChnosas Orchim!"*

Comment: I don't see it in the chapter that starts on [this page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30791&pgnum=20).

Comment: Go to http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/250.pdf, page 36

Comment: This is interesting information, but it doesn't appear to answer the question.